# How to assign deciles in a grouped data using dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following data frame with data for around 1700 counties:

```
# A tibble: 47,898 x 3
# Groups:   countyfips [1,774]
   countyfips day_month_year case_rate
        <int> <date>             <dbl>
 1       1001 2020-01-12             0
 2       1001 2020-01-19             0
 3       1001 2020-01-26             0
 4       1001 2020-02-02             0
 5       1001 2020-02-09             0
 6       1001 2020-02-16             0
 7       1001 2020-02-23             0
 8       1001 2020-03-01             0
 9       1001 2020-03-08             0
10       1001 2020-03-15             0
# … with 47,888 more rows
```

I would like to group them by the date and then assign them into quartiles based on the case rate at the given time (to compare them with other counties at the same time).

I have tried the code:

```
Affinity_County_Weekly.csv %>% group_by(day_month_year) %>% mutate(case_rate_decile = ntile(data = case_rate, 10, na.rm = TRUE))
```

But that returns the following error:

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `case_rate_decile`.
x unused arguments (data = case_rate, na.rm = TRUE)
ℹ Input `case_rate_decile` is `ntile(data = case_rate, 10, na.rm = TRUE)`.
ℹ The error occured in group 1: day_month_year = 2020-01-12.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

How do I do this with the dplyr functions?

Comment: What you want is to compute to which quantile belongs `case_rate` and obtain ten quantiles?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you are using the explicit args `data`  and `na.rm` for ntile; those are not formal parameters. `ntile` takes `x` and `n`.

```
Affinity_County_Weekly.csv %>%
  group_by(day_month_year) %>%
  mutate(case_rate_decile = ntile(x = case_rate, 10))
```

should do the trick. If there are NAs in the case_rate then they will be ignored for the purposes of computing the quantiles regardless, but will be preserved in the output data.